# Why isn't my form aligning in the center of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a form to add a book to this imaginary library website. My form tag is wrapped in a div but with this CSS it's just stuck to the left of the screen and I'm not sure why.

```
.form-container {
    padding: 50px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and show a sample of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`margin: auto` doesn't mix with `display: inline-block`. I recommend you to use something like that:

```css
.form-container {
    padding: 50px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

It centers `form-container` and sets `max-width` of the form so it's not as big. I think this is what you wanted to achieve.

You can add this property `display: block` but if `form-container` is a `div`, you don't have to do it beacuse the default `display` is `block` for divs

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of using `margin-left` and a specific `width` size. E.G if the parent width is 100% and width is 50%, a margin left of 25% will always resolve the element to the center.

As @isherwood stated, you will want different widths for each type of device (mobiles/laptops/ipads ect. ect.). How to tailor styles to specific devices can be found at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .form-container {
        padding: 50px;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border:solid black 3px;
        margin-left:25%;
        background-color:grey;
        width:50%;
    }
    #mainSection{
      background-color:red;
      padding:25%;
      padding-left:0%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainSection">
      Here is some content and the form should be centered below
      <div class="form-container">
        <input type="text" default="Here is the form">
        <button>Test button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @isherwood expand on that comment. Personally I've found percentages great for dynamic web design as it makes screen real estate a breeze to calculate. Why are `50%` wide forms not in use? Regardless, please do not misunderstand me, `50%` was an example. a 98% width form would then have a margin left of `1%` to center for example.

Comment: @isherwood ah, right you are! No, the usage of device-specific styles is something I *do* use, but assumed would be done in the OPs example. I will edit my response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex` will align your form in the center of the screen.

```
.form-container {
    padding: 50px;
    background: blue; /*to see the form*/
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* center your form horizontally*/
    align-items: center; /* center your form vertically*/
}
```